# Conditionally run MySQL query

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, session-variables

I'm trying to conditionally run a MySQL query based on a session variable.

For instance, say we'd have a session variable called `@full` which can either contain `0` or `1`. When this is `1`, I would like to truncate some table.

Any idea how to write this nicely? I know that I could for instance rewrite it to a `DELETE` like

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE @full = 1
```

However, this feels like a hack and I'd prefer not to do it this way. Any idea on how to run the `TRUNCATE` query conditionally?

Comment: You need to do it in a procedure.

Comment: I'm afraid your way to do PHP and handle SQL opens HUGE security flaws (sql injection, etc). Think it again.